# Bessel_1841 to Mercator in Python

Tags: python, wgs84, utm, pyproj

Despite similar Q&As I can't seem to get my answer.

So I have this set of coordinate (124616.1535508, 486555.4631204) are mapped to the Bessel_1841 coordinate space. I'd like to transform these coordinates into a latlong's that can plotted in google maps.

I've tried several options none of which give me the desired location:

```
import utm
print(utm.to_latlon(124616.1535508, 486555.4631204, 32, 'U'))
(4.394248331543074, 5.61858563235919)


import pyproj
p = pyproj.Proj(init='epsg:27700')
lon, lat = p(124616.1535508, 486555.4631204, inverse=True)
print(lat, lon)
(54.2004456912487 -6.223076560046059)
```

Comment: Welcome ! When you say "this website" > what's the website tou talking of ? Your coordinates are not WGS84 or it would be lat/long (geographic coordinates). As you can see in your code, they are in UTM (projected coordinates).

Comment: Thanks, and apologies - forgot to link the website. Could you elaborate on your statement? As i understand these (124616.1535508, 486555.4631204) are WGS84 and these (-7.82048005773963e+21, 1.1872122374504812e+25) latlong which work in google maps.

Comment: Ah, so if I understand correctly both are WGS84, the former is in degree's and latter in meters? Still, how do I convert these?

Comment: They are unlikely to be in 27700 with is a British projection (though that point falls in Northern Ireland which has it's own projection), Neither of the points you show are in lat/lon which is limited to +/-180,+/-90 - first might be UTM 2nd is google mercator (3857)

Comment: Ok, my assumptions were way off then. Any ideas regarding conversion, I'm pretty stuck.

Comment: Edited my question: Turns turns out my original coordinates are using the Bessel_1841 system.

Comment: If your data should be near Amsterdam, it could be `Amersfoort / RD New` or `Old`, EPSG:28992 or 28991 (instead of 27700).

Comment: @AndreJ Many thanks, 'EPSG:28991' works. Where can I find the correct code in the future?

Comment: @CharlesFried have a try here : http://epsg.io/

Answer (score 2):

With help from @AndreJ, the key was to change to the correct EPSG code:

```
import pyproj
p = pyproj.Proj(init='EPSG:28991')
lon, lat = p(124616.1535508, 486555.4631204, inverse=True)
print(lat, lon)
```

EDIT: To find the right EPSG code go to http://spatialreference.org/ and type in your location. Then try each one, for me it was the last one.